# JSON и Python (юникод)

Tags: python-3.x, json, unicode

Итак, есть json файл с всякими данными. Я беру весь json и кидаю его в программу в массив (массив из объектов).

Далее парсю страничку и все новые данные что надо помещаю в объект. Этот объект с помощью append помещаю в тот массив из всех объектов. Далее

```
json.dump(mass, file, sort_keys=True, ensure_ascii=False, indent=1)
```

Вроде нормально все было, все работало, но не долго.

1 раз мне попался в тексте с сайта значок пустого треугольника △, в следствии чего поплыло все:

При дампа выдало ошибку:

> ```
> Exception has occurred: UnicodeEncodeError
>  'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u25b3' in position 10: character 
>   maps to <undefined>
> ```

После чего в 1-й файл JSON (Использую команду выше) (Типо backup) в который я дампал код все задампалось в одинарных кавычках, а во второй задампалось все ровно до момента с ключем и значением, в котором и был этот треугольник, в следствии чего все ключи:значения потерялись, как и скобки в конце объекта и знак закрытия массива.

P.S. Дампал в оба файла одной и той же командой т.е. Выход один и тот же должен быть

Код JSON на входе выглядел примерно вот так (чисто пример):

```
[
 {
  "Dude" : "Алиса",
  "Cat" : "Shiper",
  "Fish" : "Uberemaka"
 }
]
```

На выходе:

```
[
 {
  "Dude" : "Миша",
  "Cat" : "Shiper"
  "Fish" : "Uberemaka"
 },
 {
  "Dude" : "Андрей",
  "Cat" :         #Текст в переменной содержал △
```

Потерян файл и данные.

Есть варианты избежать такой фигни с символами?

Comment: `file` открыт с кодировкой, поддерживающей юникод?

Comment: 1 - открывать файл на запись с кодировкой utf-8; 2 - или использовать `ensure_ascii=True` вместо `ensure_ascii=False`, тогда в файл треугольник запишется как `\u25b3`, но принимающая сторона его успешно распознает. Ну и кириллица тоже будет закодирована аналогичным образом.

Comment: `ensure_ascii=True` нельзя, ибо русский текст (в JSON он с True будет как юникод)

Comment: Все, помогло. insolor Спасибо